# Reading Excel file have password in c#

Tags: c#

I have 1 excel file with password. I want to create a package to store it and retrieve its sheets.

```
private static ExcelPackage _epInstance;
static string password = "password";

                    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo, password))
                    {
                        if (_epInstance == null) // ExcelPackage
                        {
                            System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
                            FileInfo templateFile = new FileInfo(filePath);
                   
                            try
                            {                                       
                              _epInstance = new ExcelPackage(templateFile);
                              _epInstance.Save();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

                            }
                        }
```

=> password right but it return:
"Can not open the package. Package is an OLE compound document. If this is an encrypted package, please supply the password"
when it run to : _epInstance = new ExcelPackage(templateFile);

i want to solve this problem, why does it need password even though i already unlocked it above.

Comment: Why are you instantiating a second instance of `ExcelPackage` when you already have one that is opened using the password?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to reopen the Excel file without the password inside the try block with `_epInstance = new ExcelPackage(templateFile);`. Try:

```
FileInfo templateFile = new FileInfo(filePath);

using (var package = new ExcelPackage(templateFile, password))
{
    if (_epInstance == null)
    {
        System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
        
        try
        {
            // Work with the Excel package here
            // You can access the worksheets, cells, etc.

            _epInstance = package; // Save the package instance to your static variable if you need to
            package.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```